# How to merge lines with word between them

Tags: merge

If i have 10 lines . between every 2 lines there is word for example (comment)

line1

comment

line2

comment

line3

comment

line4

is there away to merge every 2 lines with the word comment to be like

line1 comment line2

line3 comment line4

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?

Comment: You should state clearly how the data is being stored (data structure) instead of giving us how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned which language you want to do this in, I'm just going to reason about how you want to approach this.

You want to read the first three lines: `line1, comment, line2`, then add this to your result. You then want to skip the next line `comment`,
then repeat this process until you run out of lines.

Here it is in JavaScript:

```js
const input = `line1
comment
line2
comment
line3
comment
line4
comment
line5
comment`;

function every2Lines(text) {
  const lines = text.split("\n");
  const result = [];

  // Read four lines
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 4) {
    // Push the three first lines to the result
    result.push(lines.slice(i, i + 3).join(" "));
  }

  return result.join("\n");
}

console.log(input);
console.log();
console.log(every2Lines(input));
```

Outputs:

```
line1 comment line2
line3 comment line4
line5 comment
```